# Does `type.__instancecheck__` implement the default behavior of `isinstance`?

Tags: python, python-3.x

[The docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#class.__instancecheck__) say the following:

> [...] If defined, called to implement `isinstance(instance, class)`.

The wording suggests that it makes a difference whether `__instancecheck__` is defined or not. I.e. it doesn't say *"Override to implement `isinstance`"* where it would be clear that the base implementation (`type.__instancecheck__`) provides the default behavior.

To be more specific I would like to know whether the following meta class results in similar behavior as if I omitted the definition of `__instancecheck__`:

```py
class Meta(type):
    def __instancecheck__(self, instance):
        return super().__instancecheck__(instance)

class Test(metaclass=Meta):
    pass

isinstance(<something>, Test)
```

My intuition says yes, but the wording of the docs makes me worry that `isinstance` takes a different path based on whether `__instancecheck__` is defined or not. In the end I would like to know whether I can fall back to `super().__instancecheck__(instance)` in my own implementation of `__instancecheck__` in order to get the default behavior.

Answer (score 0):

`isinstance` doesn't act any different with or without `__instancecheck__` being defined. Also, "falling back" on `super().__instancecheck__(instance)` is unnecessary. According to https://bugs.python.org/issue35083, "any object `x` is always considered to be an instance of
`type(x)`, and this cannot be overridden."

Comment: Do you have any evidence supporting that claim? The documentation says *"If defined, [...]"* which suggests that there is some kind of branching based on `__instancecheck__` being defined. Also I don't understand why `super().__instancecheck__(instance)` would be unnecessary. If I'm implementing my own logic in `__instancecheck__` and then for some condition I want the default behavior, this is exactly what I planned to use.